# Application freezing After 10-15 min without given any event - [Inactive] state - iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

Here I used this code for stay away application. This code will use to prevent to iPad lock screen.
The app is running in the foreground but is currently not receiving events. (It may be executing other code though.)

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].idleTimerDisabled = YES;
```

When i used 2hr application will worked perfectly but when i didn't give any event in application then after 10min application is hang because application in `Inactive` state thats why I am not able to use application, Only kill application option is to use again application.

Even application will freeze in simulator also.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

In the documentation they says:

This is done for the purposes of conserving power. However, apps that don't have user input except for the accelerometer—games, for instance—can, by setting this property to YES, disable the “idle timer” to avert system sleep.

So with minimal user interaction the system lets the application to work properly. When there is absolutely no interaction the system take it to the inactive state. They have also mention an important note in the documentation that what type of application can use this timer. When you absolutely have no interaction with application, the system is moving it to inactive state.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIApplication/idleTimerDisabled

Hope this will guide you.